# Showing that if $N \le G$ is finite minimal normal with every simple homomorphic image abelian, then it is abelian itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been working on the following problem, with no success so far:

"Let $N$ be a finite minimal normal subgroup of a group $G$, and suppose $N$  has the property that every simple homomorphic image is abelian.  Show that $N$ is abelian."

I am told to use the result of the previous problem, "If $H \le G$, then $G' \le H$ iff $H \triangleleft G$ and $G/H$ is abelian."

($G'$ is the derived subgroup of $G$)

Here are some of my thoughts so far:

It seems the natural subgroup to consider here would be $N \le G$.  Since $G' \triangleleft G$ but $N$ is minimal normal, $G' \not\le N$, which implies that (since we assume $N \triangleleft G$) $G/N$ is not abelian.  If this leads us to the proof, I certainly don't see how it does so.

Generally, for showing that a subgroup is abelian, we could show that $N'$ is trivial.  We could also establish it as the homomorphic image of some abelian group or subgroup, but in this problem it seems it would be a preimage, but then abelian-ness may not be preserved (consider the zero homomorphism from a non-abelian group).

I would really appreciate a HINT on where to go with this.  I would also appreciate whatever commentary and discussion anyone has to offer on how to go about thinking about this (and the same holds for all of my questions), because I feel this is really where I lack experience.  Having attended actual lectures very little, I feel like I don't really know 'how to think' about problems.

Thanks for the help, as always.

Comment: In the nonabelian group of order 6, the derived subgroup is actually equal to the (unique) minimal normal subgroup. I think you more need to consider N' as in Andreas's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argue like this.

Consider a maximal normal subgroup $M$ of $N$. (So $M$ is a proper subgroup of $N$, it is normal in $N$, and it is not properly contained in any proper normal subgroup of $N$.)

Then $N/M$ is a [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theorem) homomorphic image of $N$, and as such is abelian.

By the result you quote, $N' \le M < N$.

**First spoiler**

> Now $N'$ is characteristic in $N$, which is normal in $G$, hence...

**Second spoiler**

> ... hence $N' < N$ is normal in $G$. Since $N$ is minimal normal, $N' = 1$, and $N$ is abelian.

Comment: Nice way of teaching!, I saw the first one through Don's answer. I am learning Andreas. +100

Comment: @BabakS., thanks a bunch!

Comment: +1 Very nice...Everything boils down to the existence of a *proper* maximal normal subgroup of $\,N\,$, which follows easily from the finiteness of $\,N\,$, so I supose this can be generalized to finitely generated $\,N\,$ and the same conditions...

Comment: Thanks!  I'll keep working with what you've provided (I've only looked at the first spoiler so far...) and comment again within a few days (the next two are quite full, not sure how much I'll get done).

Comment: I got it after the first spoiler!  I agree with Babak, that is a really nice way of answering when only a hint is desired, as it allows the one asking to work things out on their own, which I appreciate (and need).

Comment: To make sure I understand this...we look at a maximal normal subgroup of $N$ in order to eliminate the possibility that $N=N'$, right?  Or at least it does do that.  And in fact that would make sense, given Jack's comment above.

Comment: @AlexPetzke thanks a lot for the appreciation. We look at a maximal normal subgroup of $N$ because the quotient will be a simple homomorphic image, so that we can appeal to the hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that.  I definitely understand that we choose $M$ because it gives us a simple homomorphic image.  I was just thinking more about its role in forcing $N'$ to be proper.